# The item App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs was specified more than once in the source parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC Project. Whenever I try to Build it this error comes up :
`The item App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs was specified more than once in the source parameter`

I googled the error and found that a reference to `App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs` might be declared twice in the `.csproj` file, but it's only mentioned once.

`Visual Studio Community 2015`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed I had two project files :

- MyProject.csproj
- MyProject.csproj.user

I deleted `.user` and now it's working fine.